# rails - asset pipeline - how to get newer version of jquery-ui included in the project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake, asset-pipeline, factory-bot

I'm having a problem with the fullcalendar js which we use directly through the plugin (not the gem which is currently version incompatible anyway).

I'm upgrading rails from `v3.2.6` to `v3.2.8`

fullcalendar is displaying the calendar ok but clicking to edit a date has a messed up ui (the action button are missgin their labels and there is no 'x' close link) and clicking to add a new event doesn't respond at all (as it's generating js errors).

I am getting these javascript errors:

Edit Event:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'curCSS'
```

New event:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N
```

Our code:

```
LISA.dayClickHandler = function(day, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  $('#event_error_container').hide();

  var hours = JSON.parse(day.getHours());
```

fullcalendar list the jquery-ui version for it as jquery-ui `1.8.23`

However the jquery version in my application's vendor/assets/javascripts is `1.8.13` (I see this by literally opening up the file and looking at the comments at the top).

My own app/assets/javascripts library does not have any jquery.js or jquery_ui.js

My app/assets/javsacript directory has application.js which includes

```
...
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// more libraries
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-autoSuggest.packed
...
```

Perhaps it might help to change my apps jquery-ui version from 1.8.13 to 1.8.23 to see if this resolves my issues but I am not sure of the right approach to do that.

Comment: Have you tried adding `jquery-ui-rails` to your Gemfile?

Comment: Apologies, it was actually there but I hadn't included it in the question.  Added.

Comment: See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a jquery-ui change ('curCSS' was removed) that was reversed (it was added back).

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921

The resolution was to download jquery-ui version 1.8.23 to vendor/assets/javascripts to replace the older version (1.8.11) and restart the server.